# Convert HTML character reference to UTF-8

Tags: php, utf-8, html-entities

I am new to PHP and character conversions so the title of my question might be missleading.

I am parsing one website and in one string, I want to parse,  is a special character like this:

```
<tag>Hello! My name is &#382;enk!</tag>
```

Now this is the text I will be inserting into my database so I need `&#382;` converted to character '`ž`' (its ASCII code).

Comment: `ž` is actually not [ASCII](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII).

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/279170/utf-8-all-the-way-through

Answer (score 2):

Use `html_entity_decode()` and explicitly specify the charset:

```
$string = html_entity_decode($string, ENT_QUOTES, "utf-8");
```

for future reference: [PHP string functions](http://php.net/manual/en/function.html-entity-decode.php)

Comment: Hello, i have already tried that but it gives me this output: ´╗┐&#382 (using &#382)

Answer (score 0):

Try below code.

```
$input = "Hello! My name is &#382";

$output = preg_replace_callback("/(&#[0-9]+;)/", function($m) { return mb_convert_encoding($m[1], "UTF-8", "HTML-ENTITIES"); }, $input);

echo $output;
```

hope this helps.

Comment: Hello, no still no luck i am getting: ´╗┐Hello! My name is &#382

Comment: There is something wrong ... because i just cant get an output i am looking for and i have tried nomerous of options from various forums before posting question here.

Answer (score 0):

**Use the below code to solve this issue**

$string_to_convert="your string";

$utf8_converted_string=utf8_encode($string_to_convert);

echo $utf8_converted_string // Output the utf8 characters

Comment: Hello, this also preduce same resoult as other possible solutions. Output is: &#382 ... i am starting to believe there is another problem somehwere ... i really have no idea what else to try.

Answer (score 0):

The problem isn't in **displaying** the data in the browser, because I tried the following and it worked perfectly:

```
<?php echo '<tag>Hello! My name is &#382;enk!</tag>'; ?>
```

The problem isn't in **saving** the data in the database.

The problem is in retrieving this character from the database.

So you need to set the format to UTF-8 before querying the database:

```
$mysqli->query("SET NAMES 'utf8'");
$mysqli->query("SET CHARACTER SET utf8");
```

If you're using mysqli:

```
$mysqli = new mysqli($db_host, $db_user, $db_password, $db_name);
if(mysqli_connect_errno()){
    printf("DB Connect failed: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
    exit();
}
// Add the UTF-8 Support
$mysqli->query("SET NAMES 'utf8'");
$mysqli->query("SET CHARACTER SET utf8");

// Query the database
$mysqli->query("SELECT column FROM `table` ...");
```

Comment: Also it's a good practice to assign the following "meta tag" at the top of your document: insert `<meta http-equiv="Content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />` into the `<head>` tag of your HTML document.